# The format of the clipboard data is not recognized

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel

While copying (Ctrl + c -> Ctrl + v) data from a filtered Excel sheet to a SharePoint online list, I keep getting this error:

```
The format of the clipboard data is not recognized
```

I checked my data in `Notepad++` and there are not unprintable characters in the data. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy and paste does not work if you have line breaks in Excel cells.
This is most likely your issue.